# My modal is displayed but there is no content inside the displayed modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I want to include a simple bootstrap modal. The code is minimal, but there seems to be something wrong.
When I click the view button the modal is displayed but no data shows up in it. 
This is my index.php:

```
<?php  
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "baps");  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tab_organizers";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
        <head>  
            <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic MySQL Data using Ajax & 
             PHP</title>  
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
            </script>  
        </head>  
        <body>  
            <br /><br />  
            <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Visitor's List</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                    <table class="table table-bordered">  
                        <tr>  
                            <th width="70%">Group Name</th>  
                            <th width="30%">View</th>  
                        </tr>  
                        <?php  
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                        {  
                        ?>  
                        <tr>  
                            <td><?php echo $row["GroupName"]; ?></td>  
                            <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo 
                                 $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                        </tr>  
                        <?php  
                        }  
                        ?>  
                 </table>  
              </div>  
           </div>  
        </body>  
    </html>  
    <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
        <div class="modal-dialog">  
            <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Visitor Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="visitor_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('.view_data').click(function(){  
                var OrganizerID = $(this).attr("id");  
                    $.ajax({  
                        url:"select.php",  
                        method:"post",  
                        data:{OrganizerID:OrganizerID},  
                        success:function(data){  
                        $('#visitor_detail').html(data);  
                        $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
                    }  
                });  
            });  
        });  
    </script>
```

This is my select.php:

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST["OrganizerID"]))  
    {  
        $output = '';  
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "baps");  
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tab_organizers WHERE OrganizerID = '".$_POST["OrganizerID"]."'";  
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
        $output .= '  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table table-bordered">';  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
            $output .='
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Record Entered on: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Datetimestamp"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Organizer ID: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["OrganizerID"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Group Name</label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["GroupName"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Contact Name</label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["ContactName"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>House or Apartment #: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Address1"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Street Name: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Address2"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>City: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Province: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Province"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Postal Code: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Country: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Title or Profession: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Title"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td><label>Home or Office #: </label></td>
                   <td>'.$row["Telephone1"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Cell Number: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Telephone2"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Fax Number: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["FaxNumber"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>School Email Address: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["SchoolGeneralEmail"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Personal Email Address: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Email"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>How did you hear about us: </label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["HowDidYouHear"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Santo`s or Karyakar`s Comments on this Organizer</label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Comments"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Diwali Invites to be send?</label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["Diwaliinvites"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Subscribe to BAPS mailing list?</label></td>
                    <td>'.$row["SubscribedToMailingList"].'</td>
                </tr>
            '; 
        }
        $output .= "</table></div>";  
        echo $output;
    }
?>
```

> my database column names are as follows: OrganizerID(int(11))
>   GroupName(varchar(240)) ContactName(varchar(50)) Address1(varchar(50))
>   Address2(varchar(50)) City(varchar(50)) Province(varchar(50))
>   PostalCode(varchar(50)) Country(varchar(50)) Title(varchar(50))
>   Telephone1(varchar(50)) Telephone2(varchar(50)) FaxNumber(varchar(50))
>   SchoolGeneralEmail(varchar(50)) Email(varchar(100))
>   SubscribedToMailingList(bit(1)) HowDidYouHear(varchar(50))
>   Comments(mediumtext) Datetimestamp(datetime) Diwaliinvites(bit(1))

Comment: What gets logged if you put `console.log(data);` after `success:function(data){`?

Comment: mmmm...let's see.. have you tried making a POST (for example using `Postman`) to the `select.php`? and see if that request gets the desired response it looks like the problem is in there (and not in the modal, that by the way is an esthetic detail not essential to the given problem of not feching any data)